# Multiple SEO friendly URL in PHP

Tags: php

I need to make SEO-friendly Url in Core PHP in any way...

```
www.example.com/product_category?cat=Men-1
to
www.example.com/product_category/Men-1
```

```
www.example.com/product_subcategory?subcat=Top Wear-12
to
www.example.com/product_subcategory/Top Wear-12
```

```
www.example.com/product?q=Men T-Shirt-1
to
www.example.com/product/Men T-Shirt-1
```

Please help anyone..

Comment: Please share more details about that problem. Is this an existing application already in production? What framework is it using? What approaches have you tried (that didn't work). Can you create a self-contained minimal example that reproduces the issue to help us understand the problem in detail?

Comment: I'm using PHP and its live site which I have created. Im not a professional PHP developer, but I have much experienced and I have created this and need some help to achieve this type of URL

Answer (score 0):

Please look into .htaccess file and making use of rewrites.

It is very confusing but you can achieve what you need. It will take a specific url that you define such as

/product_category/something-here

And send it to the server as

/product_category?cat=something-here

Or if you are using laravel or other similar url route system you would be able to simply alter routes.

Comment: +1 for a single page I can understand but I have more than one pages, for the category, sub category, and product as well